# Appending text to div without overwriting existing childs in dojo

Tags: javascript, html, dojo

I have the following HTML template:

```
<div class="thisDiv" data-dojo-attach-point="thisDivAttachPoint">
        <img src="images/someImage.png" class="someImage"
                data-dojo-attach-event="onClick:_doSomething"/>
</div>
```

Now, in my accompanying js, I am evaluating some text which I want to place in this `div` before the `image`.

```
var stringToPlace = "This is the text for thisDiv";
this.thisDivAttachPoint.innerHTML = stringToPlace;
```

However, doing this results in:

```
<div class="thisDiv" data-dojo-attach-point="thisDivAttachPoint">
   This is the text for thisDiv
</div>
```

That is, the image is getting lost.

What do I do so that the result is such that the text is "prepended" before the image. That is:

```
<div class="thisDiv" data-dojo-attach-point="thisDivAttachPoint">
    This is the text for thisDiv
        <img src="images/someImage.png" class="someImage"
                data-dojo-attach-event="onClick:_doSomething"/>
</div>
```

I also tried:

```
domConstruct.place(stringToPlace, this.thisDivAttachPoint, "first");
```

But this gives error as:

```
parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'
```

I also tried:

```
this.thisDivAttachPoint.innerHTML = stringToPlace + this.thisDivAttachPoint.innerHTML;
```

After doing this, visually it is as expected i.e. text and then the image. However, the `onClick:_doSomething` on the image is not getting invoked. What am I missing? Inspecting the element shows that `onClick:_doSomething` is there. But click doesn't do anything. No errors.

Answer (score 0):

This worked.

```
domConstruct.place(domConstruct.toDom(stringToPlace), this.thisDivAttachPoint, "first");
```

This results exactly in what I want. Issue was, we need to convert the `String` to `node` before using in `place`.

[Dom-Construct Documentation](https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dojo/dom-construct.html)